# How do I display messages using an array or object

Tags: javascript

I've created a random generator game and this is a RandomNumber() function that will display the message if the user keys in the correct or wrong number. Does anyone knows how to display the message using an array or object method? For example, "`Your guess number 1 is 5 and it is too low`", "`Your guess number 2 is 23 and it is too high`". So the maximum number a user have is 5 tries.

```
function RandomNumber()
{    
       if (!this.guesses) 
        {
          this.guesses = 1;
        } 
        
        else 
        {
            this.guesses++;
            
                if (this.guesses > 5) 
                {
                document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML="No more tries";
                document.getElementById("guessing").disabled=true;
                return;
                }
        }    
            //get value from random number textbox
            var lol=document.getElementById("guess").value;
            //get new value from user 
            var ass=document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    
                if(ass == lol)//if user guess correctly
                    {
                        document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML="Correct"
                    }
                else if(ass!=lol)//if user guess wrongly
                    {
                        document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML="Not correct"

                    }
}
```

Comment: show us what you've tried so far... (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: @Kyle I haven't tried anything because I do not know how to start

Comment: var obj =  {1: "Message1", 2:"message2"}  obj[1]

Comment: @Stefan Avramovic what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMessage(correctNumber, guess, guessNumber) {
    const highOrLow = guess > correctNumber?"too high.":"too low.";
    return `Your guess number ${guessNumber} is ${guess} and it is ${highOrLow}`;
}

const message = getMessage(3, 5, 1); // message now equals "Your guess number 1 is 5 and it is too high."
```

Explanation:

The first line `const highOrLow = guess > correctNumber?"too high.":"too low.";` creates the part of the string that says "too high" or "too low" using a ternary operator. If guess is too high then `highOrLow` will equal "too high.". It will equal "too low." otherwise. The second line uses javascripts string templating to create the final string. The `${variable}` part of the string are replaced with the value of `variable`.

Keep in mind this function doesn't account for when "guess" and "correctNumber" are equal.

This doesn't use an array or object but there is no reason to use an array or object. If you really want to put it in an object then do:

`var o = {message: getMessage(3, 5, 1)}`

but I don't see why you would need to do that.

Comment: what does the const message = getMessage(3,5,1); means

Comment: how am I allow it to display on the web? Do I make adjustment under my RandNumber() method?

Comment: @NgLengPoh It creates a variable named message and assigns it the value returned by `getMessage(3, 5, 1)`. `getMessage(3, 5, 1)` calls the function `getMessage` with the values `3, 5, 1` as parameters. Those values are used by the function to create the string. The string that that function creates is stored in the variable named `message`. The `const` keyword in javascript is just a way of creating variables that cannot have their values changed.

Comment: @NgLengPoh use something like `document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=getMessage(correctNumber, guess, guessNumber)`. You need to fill in the values for correctNumber, guess and guessnumber. Yes you can use that function in the RandNumber method if you want, the function can be used to create the message anywhere you want in your code provided you pass the correct values.

Comment: do I need to create a <span> in my form to allow it to be displayed?

Comment: @NgLengPoh Yes you'll need some element to display the message within and a span should work

Comment: so document.getElementById.... is being replaced by my old version of document.getElementById.... for the display under my RandomNumber() method?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this method that you have shown me